# Cannot reach Synology NAS with Windows Explorer

Tags: network-share, network-attached-storage, synology, windows-explorer

I cannot access the office Synology NAS from one of the clients on the network, using Windows Explorer.
When I click its icon in the Network section, I get an error:

> "Couldn't access \\SynologyNAS" "Error 0x80070035. Network path not
> found"

Windows problem diagnosis actually doesn't find any problems.

However, all other applications can locate the SMB shares:

- This NAS is accessible through Win Explorer from every other client on the local network.
- From this Windows workstation, the Synology Drive Client app, as well as Synology Assistant can access and use it.
- Going to the NAS's IP in the browser from this machine, it's accessible.

Only Windows Explorer is not getting through from this machine. It's important for users to be able to do that (it's also the only way they know how).
Here is the output of some diagnostic commands suggested in Synology forums:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nbtstat -r

  Statistik zur NetBIOS-Namensauflösung und -Registrierung
------------------------------------------------------------------

  Durch Broadcast aufgelöst    = 11
  Durch Namenserver aufgelöst   = 0
  Durch Broadcast registriert   = 27
  Durch Namenserver registriert = 0
  Durch Broadcast aufgelöste NetBIOS-Namen
--------------------------------------------------
ZENTRUMLG
ZENTRUMLG <00>
FALKELGD-LE
FALKELGD-LE
ZENTRUMLG <00>
ZENTRUMLG
FALKELGD-LE
ZENTRUMLG <00>
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nbtstat -A 192.168.0.3

Ethernet:
Knoten-IP-Adresse: [192.168.0.52] Bereichskennung: []

    NetBIOS-Namentabelle des Remotecomputers
     Name               Typ          Status
  ---------------------------------------------
  ZENTRUMLG      <00>  EINDEUTIG   Registriert
  ZENTRUMLG      <03>  EINDEUTIG   Registriert
  ZENTRUMLG      <20>  EINDEUTIG   Registriert
  WORKGROUP      <00>  GRUPPE      Registriert
  WORKGROUP      <1E>  GRUPPE      Registriert
  MAC Adresse = 00-00-00-00-00-00
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nbtstat -a ZentrumLG

Ethernet:
Knoten-IP-Adresse: [192.168.0.52] Bereichskennung: []

    NetBIOS-Namentabelle des Remotecomputers
     Name               Typ          Status
  ---------------------------------------------
  ZENTRUMLG      <00>  EINDEUTIG   Registriert
  ZENTRUMLG      <03>  EINDEUTIG   Registriert
  ZENTRUMLG      <20>  EINDEUTIG   Registriert
  WORKGROUP      <00>  GRUPPE      Registriert
  WORKGROUP      <1E>  GRUPPE      Registriert
  MAC Adresse = 00-00-00-00-00-00
```

Comment: It seems like DNS issue on the client. Name "SynologyNAS" cannot be resolved. What is the ouptut of cmd: nslookup SynologyNAS

Comment: Here's the output:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup ZentrumLG
Server:  ns2.chello-dsl.at
Address:  195.58.161.123
*** ZentrumLG wurde von ns2.chello-dsl.at nicht gefunden: Non-existent domain.

I'm not quite sure why that server is there - it appears to ask a DNS server on the internet, but this NAS is of course only in the local namespace

Comment: Also, on another local client that *can* reach the NAS, the output is the same.